# d3 drag multiple text elements inside a group SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, text

I am new to using d3.js.  I am trying to append multiple text elements in a svg group.  With that, I want to be able to drag the group of multiple text.
So for an example:

```
    export function testNode (config = {}) {
    let { svg, rectX, rectY, text1, text2 } = config
    var data = [{ x: rectX, y:rectY, label: text1, label2: text2, labelX: rectX + 100, labelY: rectY + 200, labelX2: rectX + 300, labelY2: rectY + 300 }]
        var group = svg.append("g")
                .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

        group.append("text")
                .data(data)
                .attr("x", (d) => { return d.labelX })
                .attr("y", (d) => { return d.labelY })
                .attr("font-size", "1em")
                .attr("color", "black")
                .text((d) => { return d.label });

            group.append("text")
                .data(data)
                .attr("x", (d) => { return d.labelX2 })
                .attr("y", (d) => { return d.labelY2 })
                .attr("font-size", ".75em")
                .attr("color", "black")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .text((d) => { return d.metricValue_01 });

function dragStarted() { 
 d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
d3.select(this).select("text")
 .attr("x", d.labelX = d3.event.x + 10)
 .attr("y", d.labelY = d3.event.y + 20);

d3.select(this).select("text")
 .attr("x", d.labelX2 = d3.event.x + 10)
 .attr("y", d.labelY2 = d3.event.y + 20);

function dragended() {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

If I use the selectAll method, the text gets clumped together. Therefore, I was wondering if I can drag the text group in their proper position based on the coordinate I give it (while being dragged).  Anyways please let me know if I need to provide any further information.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the second label, but don't want to use `selectAll` as it selects both, you can give the labels classes when appending and select those when dragging:

```
d3.select(this).select(".bigLabel")
 .attr("x", d.labelX = d3.event.x + 10)
 .attr("y", d.labelY = d3.event.y + 20);

d3.select(this).select(".smallLabel")
 .attr("x", d.labelX2 = d3.event.x + 10)
 .attr("y", d.labelY2 = d3.event.y + 20);
```

Though of course this will set the same coordinate for both labels unless you specify an offset, as below:

```js
var data = [
 { x: 100, x2: 100, y: 100, y2: 120, label: "label1", value: "17%" },
 { x: 300, x2: 300, y: 200, y2: 220, label: "label2", value: "83%" },
 { x: 100, x2: 100, y: 200, y2: 220, label: "label3", value: "11%" },
 { x: 300, x2: 300, y: 100, y2: 120, label: "label4", value: "96%" }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var labels = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on("drag",drag));
    
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", "1em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; })
  .attr("class","label1");
     
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", ".75em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x2;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y2;})  
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .attr("class","label2");

function drag(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this)
    .select(".label1")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x = x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y = y; })
  d3.select(this)
    .select(".label2")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x2 = x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y2 = y + 20; })    
    
}
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
```

I won't dive into the alternative in too much depth, but it applies the drag to the `g`, positioning both text labels at the same time. This can handle irregular spacing between sibling labels easier than the above:

```js
var data = [
 { x: 100, y: 100, label: "label1", value: "17%" },
 { x: 300, y: 200, label: "label2", value: "83%" },
 { x: 100, y: 200, label: "label3", value: "11%" },
 { x: 300, y: 100, label: "label4", value: "96%" }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var labels = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d) { 
    return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")"; 
  })
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", drag));
    
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", "1em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
     
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", ".75em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  
function drag(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform","translate("+[d.x=d3.event.x,d.y=d3.event.y]+")"); 
}
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
```

*Also, there is no need to use `append("text").data(data)`, this is not doing anything - your datum is already bound to the newly appended element*

*Lastly, you can make this work with selectAll() if you set attributes using the second parameter of any provided function when setting attributes: `(d,i)=>...` i is the index of the element, so if your sibling labels are regularly spaced, you can use something like:*

```js
var data = [
 { x: 100, y: 100, label: "label1", value: "17%" },
 { x: 300, y: 200, label: "label2", value: "83%" },
 { x: 100, y: 200, label: "label3", value: "11%" },
 { x: 300, y: 100, label: "label4", value: "96%" }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var labels = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on("drag",drag));
    
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", "1em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; })
     
labels.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", ".75em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 20;})  
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })

function drag(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x = x; })
    .attr("y", function(d,i) { d.y = y;
      return d.y + i * 20;
    })
}
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just added the class attribute to the group.  I need it to drag together, because actually both elements are inside a rectangle of an svg group.  Really appreciate it!